# How disable button when nothing in textfield

Tags: java, button

I have a quick question. Im making a little program here but now im stuck on a point.

I have a TextField and a button with which you can see the amount if you click on it.
But i want to disable the button when nothing is written in the TextField, so when you write something in the textfield the button must be able to press again.

Can anyone help me on this? i've been searching for a answer but i cant find it.

Thank you.

Comment: Which script-language?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Im very sorry, I'm using Java!(netBeans)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 /*
     * jsch-0.1.50 - MyPane.java, Feb 3, 2014 3:05:03 PM
     * 
     * Copyright 2014 Varra Ltd, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * Varra proprietary/confidential. Use is subject to license terms.
     */
    package com.varra.threading.voltaile;

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    /**
     * TODO Description go here.
     * 
     * @author <a href="mailto:varra@outlook.com">Rajakrishna V.
     *         Reddy</a>
     * @version 1.0
     * 
     */
    public class MyPane extends JPanel
    {

        /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3089223598850357054L;

        /** The tf. */
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField(30);

        /** The button. */
        final JButton button = new JButton("BUTTON");

        /**
         * Instantiates a new my pane.
         */
        public MyPane()
        {
            add(tf);
            add(button);
            button.setEnabled(false);
            new Thread(target).start();
            tf.addActionListener(actionListener);
        }

        final ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Enable"))
                {
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Disable"))
                {
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        };

        final Runnable target = new Runnable()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    final ActionListener[] listeners = tf.getActionListeners();
                    for (ActionListener listener : listeners)
                    {
                        if (tf.getText().trim().length() > 0)
                        {
                            final ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(tf, 1, "Enable");
                            listener.actionPerformed(event);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            final ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(tf, 1, "Disable");
                            listener.actionPerformed(event);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        /**
         * Entry point to the entire application, contains the list of args to pass
         * the user defined values.
         * 
         * @param args
         *            the arguments
         */
        public static void main(String... args)
        {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.getContentPane().add(new MyPane());
            frame.setSize(800, 600);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is to make you understand what happens under hoods when you use DocumentListener. But the above answer is best usage of textField in production.

Comment: Good... Have FUN to be coding ... :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple! All you need to do is add an listener to the document created for the text field you are using and then call an enable method whenever a change is detected. Within this method you enable the button

Eg

```
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    enableButton();
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    enableButton();
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    enableButton();
}

public void enableButton() {
     if (textField.getText().equals(""))
     {
        button.setEnabled(false);
     }
     else
     {
        button.setEnabled(true);
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Im sorry but im a beginner, can you explain this? because i dont know what to do